# Generate "flat" hello world binary on Linux with GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I'm trying to make gcc generate a "flat binary" hello world program, i.e. a relocatable self contained program that consists of one section combining .text, .data and .rodata and whose entry and exit points are simply the beginning and end of the file.

So far I've written the following C code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>

static inline ssize_t _write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count) {
  ssize_t ret;

  __asm__ volatile(
    "mov %0, %%rdi\n"
    "mov %1, %%rsi\n"
    "mov %2, %%rdx\n"
    "mov $1, %%rax\n"
    "syscall\n"
    :
    : "g"(fd), "g"(buf), "g"(count));

  __asm__ volatile ("mov %%rax, %0" : "=r"(ret));

  return ret;
}

int _start() {
  char const *msg = "hello world\n";

  _write(0, msg, sizeof(msg));

  __builtin_unreachable(); /* don't generate ret statement */
}
```

And I'm trying to compile this with:

```
gcc -std=c99 -fPIC -fno-stack-protector -c hello.c -o hello.o
gcc -N -nostdlib -fno-stack-protector hello.c -o hello
```

But this results in:

```
/usr/bin/ld: hello: error: PHDR segment not covered by LOAD segment
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This seems to be caused by the `-N` linker option but I don't know why exactly.

I'm working on `5.12.12-arch1-1` with GCC `11.1.0` and GNU ld `2.36.1`.

Comment: That is odd since you do pass -fPIE. I suggest compiling and linking as separate steps, so you can look at the object file and what the linker is trying to link.

Comment: Please specify your Linux distribution, GCC and ld versions. (Not that I know the answer, but it would help.)

Comment: @user253751: That seems to solve the first problem.

Comment: Please don't "fix" problems in the question in response to comments, or worse, answers. If you do that then earlier comments and (possible) answers will become wrong, and sooner or later the question itself rather useless. If you have multiple problems then delete and repost as multiple questions, adding actual answers to the problems that have been solved.

Comment: For the entry point to be the beginning of the *file*, are you wanting it to still be an ELF executable?  If so, you're going to need the CPU to execute the ELF header.  According to `ndisasm -b64 /bin/ls`, that starts out with `jg 0x47` then two back-to-back REX prefixes on a memory-source `add r8b,[rcx]` which will crash if it executes, so unless the `jg` is taken (I think no with initial Linux EFLAGS), or you can put different bytes after the 4-byte ELF signature (https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html for 32-bit code in header), you have a problem.

Comment: You could also get everything in the `.text` section by using `__attribute__((section(".text")))` on your string.  (On a `char[]` array, don't use an anonymous string literal object, just a quoted string as an array initializer.)